# ngFor is re-rendering the content on the change of observables

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, ngfor

I am unable to find why **ngFor** re-renders the content of an array of Observable, **whenever the value of any observable changes**.

I tried to create an array of observables. There are 3 observable in the array. Unlike the other two observables, **the third observable emits the values in the interval of 1 second**.

Whenever the new value is emitted by the third observable, **the ngFor re-iterates on the whole array**. To verify this behaviour, **I created a function to returns the count in increasing order. Whenever this 'getCount' method will be called from the template inside the ngFor, it will return the count and increase the count by one**.

[You can find the code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnvgrq)

I want to know **why ngFor re-renders the whole content** on the change of one observable and **why angular is throwing the error** 
"`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 47245'. Current value: 'null: 47248'.`"

Comment: that is an expected behavior. you may use [trackby](https://medium.com/better-programming/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878) to improve *ngFor iteration. ([more info](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf))

Comment: This is not the issue of ngFor. it's about `getCount()`. Try removing it from Html file

Answer (score 2):

It happens because by default angular keeps track of these objects using their object references and when we made some changes to the array we are returning new object references. So angular does not know whether it is old objects collection or not and that’s why it destroys old list and then recreates them.

To avoid rerendering you can make use of `trackBy` function.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wts2we)

Check the DOM elements while clicking `Refresh Employees` button.

And also here's a blog which clearly explains about it.

[trackby-with-ngfor-directives-in-angular](https://medium.com/@jinalshah999/trackby-with-ngfor-directives-in-angular-application-bd4d0db288eb)

You can also use `trackBy` in observables. I have made some modifications using your example and please concentrate on the developer tools and you can see only the observable gets rendered and it won't rerender the ngFor.

Observables with trackby => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbhmps

Comment: can we use trackBy with Observables? In my example, I am using array of observables and I am not able to map the observables using trackBy.

Comment: @NPrafull I have updated the answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer @ng-suhas. What would happen when I use getCount() along with trackBy. Why using getCount()  updating all the divs?

Comment: @NPrafull we should avoid doing function calls in the Angular template. Here is a good blog which explains why we should not use it https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496. Let me know if this helps